# Build a where clause from comma separated list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that accepts a comma separated list of values as a parameter

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT( @userList, ','))
```

I want to change the where clause to use a like for each value

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE 'value1%' 
   OR username LIKE 'value2%' ...
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any ideas?

Comment: why?  it will probably be slower

Comment: comma-separated and SQL don't mix well.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the OP is not suggesting he change his SP to use a TABLE VALUE PARAMETER (the obvious best solution) -- he has a working solution (with string split function) unlikely any other way to process a comma separated list of values solution is going to be better

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to build a gigantic list of `OR` conditions, just *join* on `LIKE`:

```
SELECT u.username, f.value
FROM dbo.users AS u
  INNER JOIN SPLIT_STRING(@userList, ',') AS f
  ON u.username LIKE f.value + '%';
```

Comment: Why is this better than using IN?

Comment: I just don't understand this question -- the user said it is working using the IN.  Why change it?  Is it to slow?  Why?  It is not clear to me.

Comment: ah ok -- so the functionality is changing

Comment: The first query is an example of how the data is coming in.  The query has to be converted to a like instead of in.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler to use `EXISTS`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT( @userList, ','))
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte c WHERE u.username LIKE c.value + '%');
```

Comment: Why is this better than using IN?

Comment: @Hogan IN is not even an option because of the use of the operator LIKE

Comment: Not what was implied by OP's question -- they said it is working using IN

Comment: @Hogan I guess the requirement of the question is an extension of the OP's working query, like *I have this* and *I want that*.

Answer (score 1):

The *real* answer here is to **not have a comma-separated list at all.** Keep your data normalized and use a Table-Valued Parameter instead.

First create a Table type

> Note the use of primary key, which gets you a free index. In this particular instance I don't think it will be used, because of the `LIKE`, but it would be useful if you were doing `=`

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.NameList TABLE (value varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then use it in your procedure

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetUserList
  @userList dbo.NameList
AS

SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @userList ul
    WHERE u.username LIKE ul.value + '%'
);
```

You use it like this

```sql
DECLARE @list dbo.NameList;
INSERT @list (value) VALUES ('value1'),('value2');

EXEC dbo.GetUserList @list;
```

And most client libraries can pass these parameters also.